# Install XFCE in elementary OS?

Tags: settings

I'd like to swap out the wingpanel at the top of the elementary screen with the XFCE motif.  Can someone direct me on how to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that the panel is _not_ the Gnome panel. It's called Wingpanel and it's made by the elementary's team.

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking, can be achieved using a custom desktop session.
Pantheon, xfce, lxde, unity are all window managers which run inside xorg sessions.

So, in-order to use xfce motif top panel, you need to replace wingpanel(elementary) to xfce4-panel in a custom desktop session.

To know in details about Xorg : [Xorg Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Xorg)

Details on window managers: [Display Managers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager)

This blog might help you find what you need: [Custom Desktop Session](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=152930&p=18)

If you just want an icon theme to make your elementary look like xfce: [elementary-xfce](https://github.com/shimmerproject/elementary-xfce)

Or if you want to retain the default pantheon-wingpanel but want to customize the style: [Customize elementary wing-panel](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/customize-elementaryos-panel/)